# How to prevent password re-generating?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, encryption

I use Hibernate annotation to encrypt password

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "crypt(?, gen_salt(...))")
private String password;
```

But after updating the entity I see in logs that password re-generated.

```
 password=crypt('$2a$...
```

How to prevent this field from another encryption while saving the object?

Comment: keep a list of existing passwords and store all the generated passwords in thre.

Comment: Your question lacks details. Right before updating, what is the content of `password` ? Is your salt the same between two iterations ?

Comment: @Lou_is, when firstly saved, password contains a hashed value, when updating it replaces with hash from previously hashed value. The salt stays the same

Comment: Understood. What do you use the password for? User authentication?

Comment: @Lou_is, yes, for user authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that configuration

`@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, updatable = false)`

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions here, my guess is you should go for the second:

Either you need the clear password for some reason, and then you should use a "decrypt" statement on table read, see [example 73 in section 2.3.19](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-read-and-write).

Or you only need to check if the user has sent the right password, and should use a **hash** function and not encryption. See the [difference between hash and encryption, and when to use each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms).